# Порядок выполнения async функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

```
var urls = [];

function workTable(__dirname, urls) {
    XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync(__dirname + "/public/scripts/parser/upload_file/table_data.xlsx")
        .then(workbook => {       
            for (let colums = 2; typeof workbook.sheet("Лист1").cell(`A${colums}`).value() != "undefined"; colums++) {
                const url = workbook.sheet("Лист1").cell(`A${colums}`).value();
                urls.push(url);
            } 
        });
}

workTable(__dirname, urls);

console.log(urls);
```

В консоли я вижу пустой массив. Я понимаю, что там асинхронная функция. Как правильно расположить await или что нужно сделать? Есть вариант поставить задержку, но хотелось бы как-то иначе это реализовать

Решение:

```
async function workTable() {
    var urls = [];
    const urlsReturn = await XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync(__dirname + "/public/scripts/parser/upload_file/table_data.xlsx").then(workbook => {       
            for (let colums = 2; typeof workbook.sheet("Лист1").cell(`A${colums}`).value() != "undefined"; colums++) {
                const url = workbook.sheet("Лист1").cell(`A${colums}`).value();
                urls.push(url);
            }
            return urls;
        });
    return urlsReturn;
}

const urls = await workTable();

console.log(urls);
```

Comment: Можно например использовать последний вариант из этого ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476674/191482

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо)